# Is there a digital color meter for Windows similar to the macOS app?

Tags: windows, display, color

As a macOS user - I'm used to there being a [native digital color meter](https://support.apple.com/guide/digital-color-meter/welcome/mac) to snag / inspect the RGB colors on screen so I can match things from the web / documents or slide decks.

[image]

I'd prefer a native / first party solution (ideally one not requiring admin permissions to install / activate), but good tools of any persuasion are always worth a consideration.

What options exist on the Windows (10 or later) side to get this function on Windows OS?

Answer (score 1):

One option from Microsoft that looks well documented, supported and regularly updated is the [Color Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/color-picker) utility that is part of the larger Microsoft PowerToys

- https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/powertoys/

[image: Color Picker on Windows 10]

It doesn't support HDR but otherwise looks to be a first-class and very capable tool for color discovery and manipulation from on-screen content.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Just Color Picker from AnnyStudio](https://annystudio.com/software/colorpicker/).

Here's why I like it so much:

1. It's portable software
2. It consists of just 1 small executable file (and a tiny `.ini` file for your saved settings)
3. It's reliable - I've never had it crash
4. It supports dark and light themes
5. It supports a wide array of colour formats
6. It supports a user-definable keyboard shortcut to capture the colour under the cursor
7. It's cross-platform (available for macOS & Windows... and hopefully Linux someday!)
8. The developer is very friendly & is open to suggestions
9. It's freeware, and the [***nice developer only encourages donations to worthy causes, which I think is very cool***](https://annystudio.com/info/#donation)

Screenshot:
[image: Just Color Picker screenshot]
*source: annystudio.com*